# Insert data to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to insert data from android to mysql database
This is php code

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123423","jacccccttt");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "insert into users (name, message) values ('$name' ,'$message') ");

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Just I want android project to post name and message to my php file.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem now?

Comment: -1 because of lack of problem description. Fix it and I'll remove the downvote. We're not here to guess what the author meant.

Comment: Show the Andriod/java code that you are using to send data to the php script. Also read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android

Comment: The data doesnt insert to database

Comment: I want the code of app activity to send the data (2 input text)  to this php

Answer (score 0):

```
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DB_Name");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
     {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
     else
     {
       echo "success";
      }


   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "insert into users (name, message) values ('$name' ,'$message') ");
}
   mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: I wand the android side